# Move and rotate 2d line

Tags: c++

How can i rotate and move a 2d line with multiple points to a new start and end point?

My predefined line has the following values.

```
std::vector<POINT> preLine = {
    { 3,3 },
    { 5,4 },
    { 7,4 },
    { 8,3 },
    { 11,2 },
    { 12,3 },
    { 15,3 },
    { 17,4 },
    { 18,6 },
};
```

Now i try to redraw the same line at another place with a different start and end point.

Comment: Please post what you have tried, preferably a [mcve], and indicate where you are having problems.

Comment: rotate the axes using [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), then do a [translation of axes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_of_axes).

Comment: Rotating, scaling, translating, etc. is discussed on many websites already. Just google for them. You may have to read up about matrices etc. Oh, and this doesn't look like C, so I removed the C tag.

Comment: I just noticed that these points do not lie on one line at all. You want to rotate/move/etc. a polygon, not a line with several points (at least not what most people consider a line: something that connects **two** points -- either ending there or extending infinitely to both sides).

Comment: I would start by adjusting all of the coordinates in `preLine` so that the first point is at `{0,0}` and the angle from the start point to the end point is 0. That will simplify the implementation, because you can rotate about the starting point, and then translate the starting point.